# Python async function loop + return argument

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a small script in Python to get Telegram notification and then take action based on message.

I'm struggling to create a loop that listen Telegram and return parsed text I need.

```
import re
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


def extract_trigger(new_message):
    return re.findall(r'\$(.+?)\b', new_message)

#@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
async def new_message_listener(event):
    #Get Message Text
    new_message = event
    print(extract_coin(str(new_message)))
    if str(new_message).find(message_filter) != -1 :
        trigger = extract_trigger(str(new_message))
        print('Found! ' + trigger[0])
        await client.disconnect()
        return trigger[0]


async def main():
    coro = await new_message_listener(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
    trigger = coro
    print(trigger)


api_id = xxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('session_read', api_id, api_hash)
user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/mychan'
message_filter = 'Trigger $'

client.start()

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I'm quite new with Python and have some difficulties with async function. At this point, the script loop and only print "none" variable in the main function.

If I use this small script I'm able to get the message but it's not "looping" on the listener.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = xxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('session_read', api_id, api_hash)

user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/mychan'

message_filter = 'Trigger $'

client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    #Get Message Text
    newMessage = event.message.message
    if newMessage.find(message_filter) != -1 :
        print('Found! ' + newMessage)
    else:
        print('Not found!')


with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Your first snippet lacks the call to `client.run_until_disconnected()`. Your second snippet seems to get the indentation wrong, placing the `with` block in the `newMessageListener` function. The `with client:` line should be at top-level, and therefore indented to the left.

Comment: @user4815162342 about the second snippet probably a copy past issue (this small script works).

about the first one, where do I have to call "client.run_until_disconnected() ? I'm struggling with this line and "await" calls. I don't get it.

Comment: Please edit the second snippet to reflect your actual code - I am struggling to understand what the code you already have looks like. As I said, the `run_until_disconnected` line must be at top-level, where it might already be in the second snippet (if it's really a copy-paste issue). This is why it's important to fix the snippet for us to help you.

Comment: @user4815162342 I edited the snipped. But ignore the second one, I just use it as example, I want to have the 1st one working :)

Comment: So why did you comment out the decorator (`@client.on(...)`) in your code? Why did you add your own `main()` that is likely incorrect instead of using the `client.run_until_disconnected()` call as shown in the example code? Did you try to structure your code exactly as in the example, and what happened when you did - was there an exception, or did it fail in some other way? It would help if you showed an earlier and cleaner version of your code and showed what went wrong.

Comment: @user4815162342 what I want to do and didn't succeed with the 2nd snippet is:
- Listen Telegram channel until I have the wanted information
- return the wanted information
- do other stuff based on information.

I was unable to do that with the example, I tried some return in the async function but I was unable to get the data.

if, in the second snippet, I let @client.on(...) I'm unable to call the function in "await new_message_listener(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))" as I have to send an argument.

Comment: *I was unable to do that with the example,* - In what way did it fail? Did you get an exception, did it hang, or do nothing?

Comment: @user4815162342 if I run the 2nd snippet, I'm able to listen in loop and print the info (inside the async def). I tried to "return newMessage" I don't know how to properly get it below the "with client". I tried some stuff but it failed as I'm not experienced with Python I probably miss something.

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer. If I understand you correctly, you would like to run the bot until a particular message appears, and after that you'd like to propagate that message and continue with the program without asyncio (and without the bot being active after that point). Is that correct?

Comment: that's exactly what I want or listen and treat the message in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second snippet is correct, but it insists on running the event loop for you using `run_until_disconnected`. This is just a convenience API, though, and you can instead run the event loop yourself. Your top-level function can fire up the bot and wait for the event callback to provide it with the information it needs, e.g. using an `asyncio.Future`:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = xxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

async def get_msg_async():
    client = TelegramClient('session_read', api_id, api_hash)
    user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/mychan'
    message_filter = 'Trigger $'

    found = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
    async def newMessageListener(event):
        newMessage = event.message.message
        if newMessage.find(message_filter) != -1 :
            print('Found! ' + newMessage)
            found.set_result(newMessage)
        else:
            print('Not found!')

    # start the client
    await client.start()
    # allow the client to run in the background and wait for
    # newMessageListener to provide the message
    return await found

def get_msg():
    return asyncio.run(get_msg_async())

# now in your sync code you should be able to use:
msg = get_msg()
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! that's exactly what I need. Just for my knowledge, is there much difference if I wanted to keep listening for message and treat them in parallel ?

Comment: @hjacquemin I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by that. I thought you wanted the message "returned" to your sync code. If the sync code continues running, you obviously can't keep listening because the event loop is no longer running. If you need to keep listening, your program has to remain async. But it's hard to give a more concrete recommendation with such a vague idea of what you actually need.